# How to bind v-model from input in one div to another div or component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have my input field in one div, and will have label in another div (as sidebar in my application). I want to update label in sidebar, as I type in input on first div.

I am happy to create second div a component if that's the way. I was reading online, and it was said we could use props to pass data to component. But I am not able to link input field to component. Please find my code as below:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#div1',
  data: {
    message: ''
  }
})

Vue.component('testp', {
  props: ['message'],
  template: '<p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>'
})

var div2 = new Vue({
   el: '#div2'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
 <input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">

</div>

<div id="div2">
 <testp></testp>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no reason to have two separate Vue instances. Like you've pointed out, the second div should be a component of the app.

Comment: Your first `Vue` instance is "controlling" only `div1` - to pass data to `div2`, which is outside of `Vue`s "control" - you could wrap both of them in a single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I have pointed out in my comments, there is no reason for you to use two separate Vue instances. What you can do is simply wrap everything within an app container, e.g. `<div id="#app">`, and then instantiate your VueJS instance on that element instead.

Then, you can use `v-bind:message="message"` on the `<testp>` component to pass in the `message` from the parent. In this sense `#div1` and `#div2` are used entirely for markup/decorative purposes and are not used as VueJS app containers in your code.

```js
Vue.component('testp', {
  props: ['message'],
  template: '<p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="div1">
    <input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <testp v-bind:message="message"></testp>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Terry! although this was sample app I was trying functionality. But in actual, my div would be in sidebar as separate template in flask. I definitely can use overall div id, and I can't think of any other scenario when I can't use parent div.

Comment: @Jay85 Would that change anything? You can still wrap all the templates and unify them under a single app container.

Answer (score 2):

As Pointed in Comment You have no reason to have two separate Vue instance and the First Answer is correct. But in some cases where you really need to have multiple Vue instances, you can actually use them in the following manner.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#div1',
  data: {
    message: ''
  }
})

Vue.component('testp', {
  props: ['message'],
  template: '<p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>'
})

var div2 = new Vue({
   el: '#div2',
  computed: {
    newMessage() {
      return app.message;
    }
  },
});
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="div1">
        <input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <testp :message="newMessage"></testp>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please observe the **computed value `newMessage` is actually getting its value form a different Vue instance (`app`) and it is also reactive**. Therefore whenever the value in first Vue instance changes, it is updated in another Vue instance.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ashwinbande/pen/xMgQQz

Comment: thanks ashwin! i like your answer as well, as this gives option if we can't have fields in same overall div. Both answers are correct, but as i have already accepted Terry's so can't accepts yours as well. but thanks!